# Unable to remove starting and ending Double Quotes, I am copying the column values to clipboard from .xlsx file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

Reading the .xlsx file using openpyxl and with pandas converting it into dataframe, copying column A values to clipboard. I prefer .xlsx not .csv since I will be getting data in .xlsx file. I am using the data in the clipboard during the automation runtime

I tried replace but unsuccessful.

```
import openpyxl
from itertools import islice
import pandas as pd

file_in = r'C:MIT_Project\TempDir\POC_Check.xlsx'

wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_in)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

ship_ref = ''
iter = sheet_obj['A']
for cell in islice(iter, 1, None):
    ship_ref = ship_ref + str(cell.value) + '\r\n'
    df = pd.DataFrame([ship_ref]).replace('"','')
    #df1 = df.replace({'\"' : ''},  regex=True)
    df.to_clipboard(index=False, header=False)
```

Result I am getting:

"96PA46609526
96PA46619595
W6LA46602329
96PA46622939
8CRA46604626
7CCA46547169
W6HA46619603
92MA46614212"

Expected Result I want:

96PA46609526
96PA46619595
W6LA46602329
96PA46622939
8CRA46604626
7CCA46547169
W6HA46619603
92MA46614212

Comment: All strings will have quotes around them. Try print(df.values)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already tried df.values which cannot give my expected result. The stored values in the df is copied to clipboard which I am going past in runtime during the module execution.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your doing without seeing the dataframe. Could you include a sample of the dataframe in the question?

Comment: Here I pasting the sample data which I am working on.                               
Ship Ref Number SalesOrdNumber Delivery Number
96PA46620731 30025178 3618413
96PA46619595 30092878 3614317
W6LA46602329 30163826 3617936
96PA46622939 30224595 3612744
W6HA46619603 30241838 3612440
CBMA46627114 30309283 3610042
8CNA46577399 30309283 3615757
8CRA46618832 30314122 3615508
96PA46622948 30321066 3612859
BXMA46622437 30334519 3612551

Comment: Why are you creating dataframes for individual cells?

Comment: Charlie: I just need 'Ship Ref Number' column values to be copied off the 3 columns. Which is the best to get my Expected Result? Let me know

Answer (score 0):

I found the work around, added the header row and removed the row so now I don't see the starting double quotes " and using replace() removed the ending double "
Thanks,